# What kind of database do product based accounting packages use?

Tags: database, product, accounting

What kind of databases do product based accounting packages such as MYOB in Australia and Tally & Wings in India use?
They don't seem to use SQL SERVER or Oracle. Their storage file appears to be totally different.
Without using any third party database package...I'm amazed at how they manage to rapidly grow by adding features.

What is the way to have your own database like those product based softwares?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

MYOB's SME option [Exo Business](http://myob.com.au/exonet) is run from a MS SQL Server. We do quite a bit of customizations on top of it because of the open nature of the data.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the databases you mention, but a lot of desktop software packages use sqlite.  It is very fast and small and has quite a bit of features.  It is also used by several other languages and frameworks such as Adobe AIR and google gears.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the big companies use ERP soulutions, Like microsoft dynamics, sap, peopple soft.

Irrespective of ERP soulution, database always require maintenance, for MDM, indexes, and performace thing.

They also archive their data into data center.

Answer (score 0):

Some findings in regard to MYOB may help you:

[forums.whirlpool.net.au/forum-replies-archive.cfm/1020841.html](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/forum-replies-archive.cfm/1020841.html)

> "My business partner spent some time
>   looking at this issue, and decoded
>   part of the MYOB file structure (I
>   think he said it was a c-tree based
>   format or something) and – as much as
>   the ODBC driver sucks – we still
>   worked out it was better to go with it
>   than develop our own solution;
>   currently doing import and export via
>   .NET in C#."